# Using a symbolic link with XAMP

Tags: xampp, localhost

I have `symbolic linker` installed on my mac, which lets me easily make a symbolic link of any folder.

I decided to make a symbolic link of my php projects folder (which is in dropbox), and place it in my XAMP htdocs folder. However if I try and accesses the folder by going to the following address:

```
http://localhost/Projects/
```

I get the following error

```
You don't have permission to access the requested directory. There is either no index document or the directory is read-protected.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
```

I have read a few things about the permissions with a symbolic link, and I did change the orginal folders permission level to read and write accesses for everyone, to no avail.

Does anyone know how to get a symbolic link folder to work with XAMP.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Owww, the following terminal command fixed the problem for me :)

```
chmod go+x Dropbox
```

:D yippee